# T SQL Update Inner Join using SELECT from OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, openquery

SQL Server: is it possible to perform an `UPDATE` based on an `INNER JOIN` that is using a `SELECT` from an `OPENQUERY`?

This is my query:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[Field1] = t2.cde
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT cde, dsc FROM OPENQUERY(test,'select "cde","dsc" from PUB.Table2') AS t2 ON t1.[Field1] = t2.dsc
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

What am I missing?

Comment: arent you missing a closing bracket? behind the openquery statement?, at least thats what it looks like on the first glance

Comment: @Isparia that is it! Just needed a 2nd pair of eyes. thanks.